# Domain mode wildfly26 remote slave connection error

Tags: wildfly, high-availability, elytron

I followed this documentation:

https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-domain-configuration/

But after all I used to get this error:

wildfly domain mode remote slave  WFLYHC0001: Could not connect to remote domain controller JBOSS-LOCAL-USER, DIGEST-MD5

This documentation doesn't remarked domain-controller config, just legacy mode, so I thougt I can use default host-slave.xml!

Answer (score 0):

I understood this a little bit.
The main problem was this snippet from host-slave.xml:

```
<domain-controller>
  <remote>
    <discovery-options>
      <static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:remote+http}" host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9990}"/>
    </discovery-options>
  </remote>
</domain-controller>
```

We must bind it with authentication-context:

```
<domain-controller>
  <remote authentication-context="hcAuthContext">
    <discovery-options>
      <static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:remote+http}" host="${jboss.domain.master.address" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9990}"/>
      </discovery-options>
  </remote>
</domain-controller>
```

But there can be another option you can connect so too:

```
<remote protocol="remote" host="${jboss.domain.master.address" port="9999" authentication-context="hcAuthContext"/>
```

**The plain remote communicate on 9999, but the discovery on 9990!**